# Access the record source of a report and loop through a field in the recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I've got an MS Access report that gets data from a query.

The data set is structured like this:

```
[field 1] [field 2] ... [email]
```

The report has a "Send invitation" button in the header, that takes all the values in the `[email]` field, builds a string of semicolon-separated addresses, and opens up an Outlook invitation.

I tried to use the `RecordsetClone` for looping through it, but I discovered that this method is not available in reports.

Is there another way to get the job done?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have a long yet inefficient solution:

```
    ' Get the recordset by performing a new query
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset: Dim MailArray As Variant
    qry = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM Registry WHERE SessionID = " & CStr(TempVars("SID").Value)
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qry)

    ' Move the recordset in an array with an esoteric formula found in StackOverflow
    With rs
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        MailArray = .GetRows(.RecordCount)
    End With

    ' Loop through the array and build the string with the email addresses separated by a semicolon
    Dim i As Integer: Dim strList As String
    If (UBound(MailArray, 2)) > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(MailArray, 2)
            strList = strList + DLookup("MailAddress", "Employee", "ID=" & (MailArray(0, i))) & ";"
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "No people enrolled in this session.", vbOKOnly, "Attenzione!"
    End If
    Erase MailArray

    ' Feed the string to Outlook
    8< -------------------------------------
```

It works, though.

PS: thanks, Harassed Dad, for the support.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim rs As Recordset
 Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Me.RecordSource)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this before, but I got (and am still getting) this error: Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1.
The Debug button highlights the "Set rs = ..." row, and the help is not very helpful (at least for my level), since the .OpenRecordset method requires one mandatory parameter only (that has been obviously passed).

Comment: Is your code in the report module or a generic code module?

Comment: I tried to change "Me.RecordSource" to a table name, and it works. So the problem looks like OpenRecordSet opens tables, but not queries? The source of my data is a query.

Comment: Oh - you don't have a parameter in the original query do you?

Comment: The query has a criteria passed through TempVars. When the "Set rs = ..." line runs the TempVar is still set. If I run the query outside the form, I have proper results; the TempVar is removed when the form is closed.